# Advanced filter over 2 sheets. Copy and Paste issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with my code that I can't solve. I have used an advanced filter which is working but now want to copy and past the 'unique filtered items' to a different sheet. 
When I run the code below it looks as though it tries to copy to Sheet2 (Table 1_Pipes) but the entries are blank?

Can someone help? Thanks

[VBA Code - Attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQcHO.png)

```
Sub Uniques()

    Dim ColRange As Range
    Dim PrintRange As Range

On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    Set ColRange = Application.InputBox("Please Select Input Data To Gather Uniques From", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    Set PrintRange = Sheets("Take Off").Range("D5001")

    ColRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=PrintRange, Unique:=True

    Worksheets("Take Off").Range("A11:AI5000").AutoFilter _
        field:=4, _
        Criteria1:="<>*-*", _
        VisibleDropDown:=True

    Range("D5001:D5010").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Table 1_Pipes").Select
        Range("B6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

Exit Sub
Errorcatch:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Please put the code in the Original Post as text and not a photo.  This way we can copy and paste and not retype.

Comment: To me it looks like you are setting a print range, then performing a copy and then setting your filter. Shouldn't it be setting your filter and then doing the copy?

Comment: I have tested your code on sample data and it copies over the unique entries from the advanced filter to the second sheet correctly. Can you provide a snapshot of your sample data on both worksheets? Also, are you running any additional macros after this macro?